# How to vertically center an H1 heading within div with min-height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this div with a background image on it that's got a min-height (400px) property applied to it. I want a heading h1 to appear over right in its vertical center.

I've used the provided my-auto class but it doesn't do anything. Even tried it along with h-100 class.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QRywbw

```
<section id="message">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8 my-auto">
<h1 class="text-right align-middle">Give <span>alternate medicine</span> a chance!</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

#message {
min-height: 400px;
background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x400) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

I want the text to be vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section id="message" class="d-flex align-items-center">
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more idiomatic bootstrap way to use flexbox vertical centering, but here is a way in vanilla css using flexbox:

```
#message {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x400) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#message h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

I often reference this as a good article on this: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get anything vertically centered is to use flex-box.

```
#message{
  min-height: 400px;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x400) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css and you can see h1 tag vertically center.

```
#message{
        min-height: 400px;
        background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1000x400) no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
    }

#message h1 {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 47%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Thanks